# How to get billing information through API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

I want to create a web page regrouping billing information from Google Cloud Platform and Amazon Web Services.
I'm looking how to retrieve billing data from GCP.
Does it exist an API to request these data ?

I have tested CloudBilling API but it seems that it just gives information about billing account and not detail on usage & cost.